# Add AWS CloudWatch alarms from custom metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, cloudwatch-alarms

I've added some custom metrics to be able to track some of our external API calls. Now I want to create some alarms to see if things work as expect.

I want to make a broad alarm that covers all errors, however, when trying to figure out what's wrong, I read that AWS doesn't aggregate custom dimensions. Does that mean I need to create another set of metrics where I leave out the *HttpMethod* and *Hostname* dimensions, or can I do this another way?

The entries looks like this:

```
"_aws": {
  "Timestamp": 1629271402304,
  "CloudWatchMetrics": [
      {
          "Dimensions": [
              [
                  "LogGroup",
                  "ServiceName",
                  "ServiceType",
                  "HttpMethod",
                  "Hostname"
              ]
          ],
          "Metrics": [
              {
                  "Name": "latency",
                  "Unit": "Milliseconds"
              },
              {
                  "Name": "errors",
                  "Unit": "Count"
              }
          ],
          "Namespace": "ExternalAPI"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to combine them?

Comment: As far as I've tried, math works when I manually add all the combinations. If I do a search, it doesn't work though.